# Is it possible & ok to use rename() instead of move_uploaded_file() when uploading a file via HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Was wondering if its ok & possible to use `rename` function isntead of `move_uploaded_file`. Are there any security issues?

The reason is I am building a `File` class that will handle all file uploads and file objects. I want to be able to move files between directories when not uploading and I want to have a 1 function called `move` that does this and I was debating whether I should use move_uploading_file or rename within that function.

Comment: You can't just add a(n optional) parameter to your move function to tell it whether its a regular file or an upload in the temp folder and use an if-statement to call the appropriate function?  That would be a lot smarter.

Comment: @developerwjk `can't` or `can`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to say with my comment before was you should do something like this:

```
function move($frompath, $topath, $isupload)
{
   if( $isupload )
   {
      //frompath should only be filename
      move_uploaded_file($frompath, $topath);
   }
   else
   {
      //frompath must be fullpath
      rename($frompath, $topath);
   } 
}
```

If for no other reason than not having to bother with passing in the temp path.  But also there is a security concern.  From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> move_uploaded_file() is both safe mode and open_basedir aware.
>   However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to
>   allow the moving of uploaded files in which filename may conflict with
>   such restrictions. move_uploaded_file() ensures the safety of this
>   operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be
>   moved.

I don't know what all destination paths PHP has blacklisted, but I know it would be a bad idea to be moving Windows dlls to c:\windows\system32.  You probably would not be doing that with rename() either, but what if you were, and someone uploaded a dll, and you called rename() instead of move_uploaded_file()?  Unlikely, but might as well do things right just in case.

Comment: This makes sense and seems like the best way to do it is to add parameter and do both. I would not be doing anything that will place uploaded files anywhere that I dont want it to be placed but I am writing a generic class so it is not always the case that I will be using it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are any security differences between the two functions; if security is your primary concern, the main thing to keep in mind is that you verify your allowable size, allowable characters, name length, allowable extensions, etc.

move_uploaded_file() is probably the more specific function for what you want to do, but if you're making a "move" function that extends beyond uploaded files, I would use rename().

Comment: Upvoted because that's what I exactly think as well.

Comment: I can check for size & type in my class as well but thank you for the answer. Yes I want to use rename since it is not really dealing with uploading files only in few cases.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that `move_uploaded_file()` works only for uploaded files.

Quoting the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename
>   is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP
>   POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

So, it's a security check, to make sure someone won't try to read your `mysql.php` file or some other fishy trick.

As for functionality, they're equivalent - except `move_uploaded_file()` is designed for it's purpose, and so it does some extra security checks.

However, you can not use `move_uploaded_file()` for other than uploaded files, it will refuse to work.

Comment: he could add those checks in to his generic move class

Comment: Could anyone give exact examples of what and how can actually happen? Indeed, the documentation quote looks serious - but in real life, is there any example of how one could exploit it?

Comment: Not sure how it could happen, but user input is always dangerous. If user managed to trick you into moving some other file somewhere, and then displaying it, it's a security risk.

Comment: @MightyPork: "If user managed to trick you into moving some other file somewhere" --- how? The path to uploaded file is generated by php. It's not affected by user input in any way. We trust sessions (that are also managed by php). How this is different?

Comment: @zerkms No idea, to be honest. Assuming you move from `$_FILES["..."]["tmp_name"]...`, to some other place, there can't be any harm if you use `rename` instead.

Comment: The other difference is `move_uploaded_file()` knows where the temp files are, and with `rename()` you'd have to tell it where they are.

Comment: @developerwjk: are you sure?

Comment: @developerwjk isnt tmp path stored in ['tmp_name'] ?

Comment: @MightyPork: if so "If you don't care about safety, they're equivalent" --- this is too pessimistic from my perspective :-) At least without even a small hint how this might be exploited - the quote from documentation (which is still the official source of truth) looks not enough argumentative.

Comment: @zerkms so there is really no security issue with using rename instead of move_uploaded_file?

Comment: I guess... still looking at the docs and trying to figure out any dangerous scenario. There certainly must be some, otherwise they wouldn't add extra function.

Comment: @GGio: I'm developing in php for 10 years by now and for my whole career I have never ever heard anything *real* about this "vulnerability"

Comment: @MightyPork: "otherwise they wouldn't add extra function" --- you're overestimating quality of decisions php dev team made years ago. Now - the team consists of really good developers and decisions to make are better discussed. Not the case for 2000s. PS: I can accept thought that some issue might existed really long ago, but then it was solved somehow and we've been left with odd function and documentation chapter.

Comment: nevermind, well I may not get the 15 points, but at least we have a link and quote, so I have that going for me, which is nice.